# How do I separate by object, not by meshes or vertices?

Tags: modeling, mesh, vertices

I’m new to Blender and I wanted to know how I can quickly separate the objects below not by their vertices/meshes but rather by each of the models themselves. I use Sketchup and Enscape as my rendering engine for Archviz. The model I download seems to have different models joined together even though each object is distanced from one another. Blender’s textures can’t be imported to Skp. Whenever I try to import the Blender exports (obj file) to Skp and I try to edit the materials there, the objects are separated by the meshes as seen in Blender. Trying to separate each by selecting vertices is a hassle since there are a lot of them per object. Please see the photos below for reference. Thank you[image]

Comment: In Edit mode press 'A' to select all the vertices then, press 'P' to separate from selection, by loose parts, or by material. See if any of these options fits your need

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure I understand what you're asking but I use two ways to separate multibody meshes into separate parts while in edit mode:

1: Select the vertices of interest and press P to separate them. A quick way to select linked vertices is to hover over one of them and press L.

2: Press P and choose "By loose parts". That will divide all separate meshes into their own objects.

Comment: But each object, ex: stove, have a lot of vertices and some objects are quite close to each other so selecting vertices of one object sometimes leads to misclicks on another object's vertices

Comment: @Carl Salen if you press L it will select a separate mesh within an object, and it won't select another mesh, even if its close or intersecting with the one selected